# How do I Create a Windows Explore Style Ribbon Bar?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm currently building an application in Windows Forms, and I would like to include a Ribbon Bar, similar to the one found above the Address Bar in Windows Explorer which contains things like Copy, Paste, Delete, Rename etc. I have provided a photo of what I am looking for as an example:

[image: Ribbon]

I have looked through various Windows Forms controls, and have not particularly found anything helpful for my situation.

I'm happy to look into third-party libraries if required, but preferably I would like something that looks clean and professional.

Cheers, Will

Comment: That type of control is known as a "ribbon", so you should be able to find free and/or paid options if you include that in your search keywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You're looking for a **Ribbon** control.

If you're looking for an open-source implementation, you can check [`RibbonWinForms`](https://github.com/RibbonWinForms/RibbonWinForms), for example...

There's an article in CodeProject with an example:

[Easily Add a Ribbon into a WinForms Application](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application)

[image: Ribbon]

---

Most 3rd-party control vendors have Ribbon controls. For example, [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/) and [Telerik](https://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx).

[image: Ribbon]

Comment: That looks perfect for what I need. Thank you very much!

Comment: Requests for off-site resources are off-topic for SO.  Answers to bad questions are bad answers because they encourage more bad questions.